# Custom exception mapping for bean validation on TomEE 7?

Tags: java, cxf, bean-validation, apache-tomee, tomee-7

## Context

We use a `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<Exception>` annotated as `@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` to handle all exceptions. Internally this `ExceptionMapper` is distinguishing between different types of exceptions to determine what information to reveal to the client.

In the case of the `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`, we return additional information about which field was invalid and why.

## Problem

We just switched from `TomEE 1.7.2 JAX-RS` to `TomEE 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT webprofile`.

With `TomEE 1.7.2 JAX-RS` we used the `openejb.jaxrs.providers.auto=true` system property, our `ExceptionMapper` was automatically found and used.

With `TomEE 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT webprofile` the property is no longer necessary to benefit from auto discovery.

However the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper` is also discovered and now acts as the preferred `ExceptionMapper` for the `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`. Our own `ExceptionMapper` does not run, and the client therefore gets no information about what went wrong during validation.

Our own `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` still handles all other exceptions.

## What I already tried

### "duplicate" the specialized `ExceptionMapper`

I placed my own `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException>` next to my resources, hoping that it takes precedence over the CXF one.

<del>Still the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper` takes precedence.</del>

**Update:** it turned out that this indeed does the trick. I don't know why my initial test didn't work.

### Disable the `ValidationExceptionMapper` via `system.properties`

In the [changelog](http://tomee.apache.org/download/tomee-2.0.0-snapshot.html) of `TomEE 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT` I noticed

> [TOMEE-1336](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1336) Support classname.activated = true/false for auto discovered providers

Looking at the corresponding [changeset](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/changelog/tomee?cs=1620677) I was hopeful that I could just disable the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper` by adding
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper.activated=false
to our `system.properties`.

This remained without effect.

## Questions

- Is this CXF or TomEE behaviour?
- How do we configure which `ExceptionMapper` takes precedence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makes some time now but think it is needed by spec but you can disable it by setting `cxf.jaxrs.skip-provider-scanning=true`.

It completely disables auto providers including the scanned ones but then you can control the one you want in `openejb-jar.xml` - surely the best and safer solution IMHO cause otherwise you depend a lot of the libs and container setup you use.

There is no priority afaik cause the exception hierarchy is used.

edit: missed a part: you need to impl `ExceptionMapper{ValidationException}` otherwise CXF one has higher priority than your own one (Exception is less specific)
edit 2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1656 for the activated support

Comment: Nice. Can you please link to the issue?